# Fonts used by The New Yorker's iOS app?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, iphone

Can somebody perhaps identify the exact fonts in use by [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/)'s iOS [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-new-yorker-magazine/id370614765?mt=8), esp. those shown the sample below? I find the whole app very well designed (both in terms of graphic design, functionality, and indeed beauty and content :)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sans used for captions is [Neutraface 2](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface2). (found that out by going to The New Yorker's [website](http://www.newyorker.com/) and looking at their CSS).

The text face was identified by [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) as [LTC Caslon Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-caslon/regular/) and it looks pretty much close to really being so.

Comment: @Drux I'm still surprised there are people not knowing it. :) Even tag description for "font-identification" you used clearly points to the WhatTheFont first.

Comment: @MarcinWolny are you also surprised that some people (and still) are not seeing who added which tags? :)